# In Python, what is the difference between using ssl.get_server_certificate and using SSLSocket.getpeercert?

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

I am wanting to use Python to retrieve the remote server certificate (not validate or check it in any way). I have retrieved the server certificate using both methods ``ssl.get_server_certificate`and`SSLSocket.getpeercert`.

The main reason I had to try `SSLSocket.getpeercert` over `ssl.get_server_certificate` was that the timeout value on the TLS handshake was not being honored with the `ssl.get_server_certificate`. One of the hosts I was trying to the the server certificate had some problem and would hang my python script during the TLS handshake and only the `SSLSocket.getpeercert` would time this out.

I also notice I cannot retrieve the server certificates from very old systems that use TLS 1.0 or even SSL with `SSLSocket.getpeercert` and there is no place to specify to the `ssl_version` like there is in `ssl.get_server_certificate`.

So I see both methods retrieve the server certificate and each seems to have different issues. But what are the differences with what each does? When would I use one over the other?

Comment: `ssl.get_server_certificate` (1) appears to assume the target is a server (2) creates a new connection and (3) may return a different certificate depending on what you provide as parameters. `SSLSocket.getpeercertificate` returns the peer certificate of the current connection.

Comment: Thanks you! That does clarify what differentiates the two functions! Do you happen to know if there is a way to timeout the Handshaking process of ssl.get_server_certificate? Every timeout I have tried only times out the socket. But when the call to get the certificate begins the handshake is allowed to go on forever and does hang. With the SSLSocket.getpeercertificate, the timeout is also valid on the Handshake I guess because as you explained, it is applied to the current connection.